# how to use context api in react js (plz answer practically)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Context = React.createContext();

const Jokefetch = () => {
  const [joke, setjoke] = useState([]);
  const dadjokes = async () => {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?page=${num}&limit=30`,
      {
        headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
      }
    );
    const jokesList = res.data.results.map((val) => {
      return {
        ...val,
        vote: 0,
        emoji: "",
      };
    });
    setjoke(jokesList);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    dadjokes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={
            dadjokes();
          }
        >
          GET-J O K E S
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Jokefetch;
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div> <Jokefetch/></div>
  )
}

export default App
```

i have created a JOKEFETCH funtion that takes data(array of obj) from api,which is always new whenever i hit the GET-JOKES button. The new data is stored in joke of usestate hook by setjoke func.I want to return this data in my main App component by may be context api(usecontext) so that i can make further actions upon in my main component

Comment: Why on earth would you use context api for this? if you don't have some nefarious plans for this data, context api is absolutely redundant. Anyway, here you can see illustrative example: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecontext-hook/

Answer (score 0):

**I have implement useContext in this scenario in the following codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-gauss-yid23o?file=/src/App.js:0-191**

***Feel free to play with the code.***

Explanation:

You can create a new file called AppContext.js with useContext hook with the function to get all the jokes and store it in the joke state as follows:

**Appcontext.js**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const AppContext = createContext(null);

export const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);
  const dadjokes = async () => {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?page=${num}&limit=30`,
      {
        headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
      }
    );

    const jokesList = res.data.results.map((val) => {
      return {
        ...val,
        vote: 0,
        emoji: ""
      };
    });
    setJoke(jokesList);
  };

  dadjokes();

  return <AppContext.Provider value={joke}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
```

This will pull the jokes from the api and set the joke state value to the array of objects. Then we pass the joke state as the value prop to AppContext.Provider

Now wrap the index.js App component with AppContextProvider as follows:

**Index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";
import { AppContextProvider } from "./AppContext";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AppContextProvider>  wrapped the App component
      <App />
    </AppContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

This will enable us to make components and use the AppContext value in any component that we want.

Now create a new component called Jokefetch.js as follows:

**Jokefetch.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./AppContext";

const Jokefetch = () => {
  const joke = useContext(AppContext);

  const [displayJokes, setDisplayJokes] = useState(false);

  const handleJokes = async () => {
    setDisplayJokes(true);
    console.log(joke);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleJokes}>GET-J O K E S</button>
        {displayJokes ? joke.map((item) => <p>{item.joke}</p>) : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Jokefetch;
```

Here, we have mapped the jokes using map function. The handleJokes function will set the displayJokes state value to true and if it is true then jokes array will be mapped to the page in a paragraph tag.

**Note here ->** We have used the useContext hook to pull the AppContext's value from AppContext.Provider. This useContext hook can be used to pull AppContext's value in any component. You can use this value in App component also using `const joke = useContext(AppContext);`

Now add the Jokefetch component in App.js as follows:

**App.js**

```
import Jokefetch from "./Jokes";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Jokefetch />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```